# Duplicate_Rule_Atomic or non Atomic

Tags: apex, visualforce, jitterbit

I have a question on duplicate rule.I am loading a list of account records in to my salesforce org using jitterbit and to eliminte the insertion of duplicate records I have a duplicate rule enabled on my account object.

My question is if i have 100 records, if duplicate is found at 50 th record, is it possible to elimate the duplicate and continue to insert the remaining 50 records using duplicate rule?

if not please suggest me a sol to achieve this funtionality

Answer (score 0):

I think it mostly depends on Jitterbit of How it handle the error records and Not with duplicate rules.

Normal data loader when face error with few records they skip those records and insert the other records in the system. So Jitterbit might also provide similar solution( I have never used it before so not quite sure here.).

The thing which might give you some trouble here is

As per Duplicate Rule docs:

> If you’re saving multiple records at the same time and your duplicate
>   rules are set to Block or Alert, records within the same save aren’t
>   compared to each other; they are only compared with records already in
>   Salesforce.

So if there are multiple records in same chunk then you won't get any error or warning in that case.